# Is any Error Code thrown by Phpunit Assert?

Tags: php, phpunit, assert, assertion, behat

Do PhpUnit Assertions throw any error code / success code -  whenever assertions are passed or failed?

for example -

```
Assert::assertEquals('$expectedValue', '$actualValue');
```

if it fails - what will be the error code?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for asking the question, very interesting to take a closer look:

Given:

```
$expected = true;
$actual = false;
```

When in use:

```
self::assertEquals($expected, $actual);
```

or:

```
$this->assertEquals($expected, $actual);
```

in a Phpunit test-case test-method, Phpunit communicates not by returning but by throwing an [***Exception***](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) in case the expectation failed and by *not* throwing any *Exception* in case it passed.

This is done in your questions [`Assert::assertEquals()`<sup>9.5.6</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.6/src/Framework/Assert.php#L320) via [`static::assertThat()`<sup>9.5.6</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.6/src/Framework/Assert.php#L2340) [evaluating the `IsEqual`<sup>9.5.6</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.6/src/Framework/Constraint/Equality/IsEqual.php#L67) constraint.

For the `evaluate()` method you can ask for a return value, which would be a boolean then (the code then `true` or `false`).

Otherwise an [`ExpectationFailedException`<sup>9.5.6</sup>](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/blob/9.5.6/src/Framework/Exception/ExpectationFailedException.php#L24) is thrown which signals a failed assertion (expectation) to the test-runner, which recognizes a test failure and marks the test as failed.

> Do PhpUnit assertions throw any error code / success code - whenever assertions are passed or failed?

In general they throw when the expectation is unmatched.

However you normally don't see it as the test-runner is handling that signal and its codified meaning:

- If all your expectation match, the result of running the test-method iteration is a *success*.
- If one of the expectations remains unmatched, the result of running the test-method iteration is a *failure*.
- If your test-method has no expectations it is considered an *incomplete test*.